# C# SQLite3 Select if null

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I want the code to do something if the thing its looking for doesn't exist in the DB. This is what I am working with currently:

```cs
const string cs = @"Data Source= ..\..\..\database.sqlite3";

await using var con = new SQLiteConnection(cs);
con.Open();
            
await using var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);

member ??= ctx.Member;
            
cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT iq FROM users WHERE id = $user_id";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$user_id", member.Id);
var r = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (r.Read())
{
    if (r["iq"] == null)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var iq = random.Next(1, 200);
                
        await cmd.DisposeAsync();
                
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users(id, iq) VALUES($member_id, $id)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$iq", iq);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("$member_id", member.Id);
                
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                
        var embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder
        {
            Title = $"IQ of {member.Username} is {iq} :brain:",
            Color = DiscordColor.Cyan
        };

        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed);  
    }
    else
    {
        var iqFinal = r["iq"];

        var embed = new DiscordEmbedBuilder 
        {
            Title = $"IQ of {member.Username} is {iqFinal} :brain:", 
            Color = DiscordColor.Cyan
        };
                        
        await ctx.Channel.SendMessageAsync(embed);   
    }
}
```

I really don't know how do make that happen, I've tried `try catch` blocks but they didn't seem to work either. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `id` is the primary key of the table, so you don't expect more than 1 rows from the statement:

```
SELECT iq FROM users WHERE id = $user_id
```

The problem with this statement is that it may not return any rows if `$user_id` does not exist in the table, so in this case `r.Read()` will return `false` and the code inside the `while` loop will never be executed.

One way to do what you want is to use aggregation:

```
SELECT MAX(iq) AS iq FROM users WHERE id = $user_id
```

which always returns a row: either the row with the `iq` where `id = $user_id` or `null` if `$user_id` does not exist in the table.

Also you should change the `while` loop to just:

```
if (r.Read()) {
    .....................
}
```

or better just:

```
r.Read();
```

because the aggregation query is guaranteed that will return exactly 1 row.

Comment: Yep it works now, thanks a lot for your answer and help!